# Return Error and view in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

Hello everyone I want to know something is there possible. Using ajax send error message if occurred else send view. you can see my code. please help me what should I do. need some suggestions

here is my example

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
  string ErrorText = string.Empty;
  if(true)
    return View("PagedList");
  }
  else
  {
    return Json(new { errorMessage = ErrorText});
  }
}
```

Ajax:-

```
function Load(page) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: page,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                success: function (data) {

                        $('#ReportLoad').empty();
                        $('#ReportLoad').append($.parseHTML(data));

                },
                 error: function (xhr, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {
                    $('#ReportErrors').empty();
                    $('#ReportErrors').html(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                    $('#ReportErrors').show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                }
            });
        }
```

I don't know I am doing right way or not Can anyone suggest whats the best way to achieve this.

Comment: you have to catch the return in your ajax request

Comment: Where is you're ajax code??

Comment: you should return HTTP Code 500 if returning error

Comment: can you please give me some sample #Cuong Le

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the error code as a `HttpStatusCodeResult`, if you just send a reply there is no way of Ajax knowing it is an error unless you check for specific text in the response.

```
 public ActionResult Test()
 {
      string ErrorText = string.Empty;
      if(true)
        return View("PagedList");
      }
      else
      {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500, ErrorText);
      }
 }
```

And then detect this with Ajax:

```
function Load(page) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: page,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                success: function (data) {

                        $('#ReportLoad').empty();
                        $('#ReportLoad').append($.parseHTML(data));

                },
                 error: function (xhr, textStatus, exceptionThrown) {
                    $('#ReportErrors').empty();
                    $('#ReportErrors').html(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                    $('#ReportErrors').show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                },
                   statusCode: {
                   500: function(response)
                   {
                       alert("internal error");
                   }
                 }
            });
        }
```

Comment: What is being shown? Have you tried debugging the response with FireBug or Chrome to see what the actual response is?

Comment: problem in this line actually i remove this line its working  and use alert its work